# Nokia Lumia 920 Group Text Issues, receiving Pic Message issues

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-920

In my Nokia Lumia 920 when I am receiving a group text or picture messages, the message received is **Media Content in this message**.
When I try to open it reads **get media content now**, but once you attempt to open it does nothing.  It has worked before, not sure why it stopped.

Comment: Have you changed any SIM settings? Tried restarting your phone?

Comment: I am not sure what my changes should be. I have restarted. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Not saying any settings *should* be changed, just thought maybe you'd changed something that had messed it up.